# How to calculate the sum of euclidean distances of each point from every other point in an RDD in Spark using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

The RDD contains 2 dimensional Vectors like the example below.

```
----------
8535,9232
---------
9343,5123
---------
9343,2943
---------
```

I want to calculate the sum of distances for every point,so I can find the ones that are the furthest way

Thanks !

Comment: You may do a [`cartesian` **product**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@cartesian[U](other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U])(implicitevidence$5:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(T,U)]) of your `RDD` with _itself_, then compute the distance of each tuple - **BE AWARE THAT THIS IS MEMORY HEAVY!**. BTW, quick question if I understood correctly, each element of the `RDD` is a **Point** _(a tuple X, Y)_ if so, why using `Vectors`?, would be better a `Tuple`?

Comment: I'm a begginer to Spark and Scala and I used this line of code to parse the csv data into an RDD

`val parsedData=data.map(s=>Vectors.dense(s.split(',').map(_.toDouble))).cache() `

Doesn't this imply that I've got a 2 dimensional vector in the RDD?

Also how do I sum the distances of each tuple afterwards in terms of code? 

Thanks again and sorry for my ignorance

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez